# Can I reference input events in the "post-if" condition in GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a GitHub Action that can be triggered via the GitHub UI (with [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)), which has a boolean flag as one of the inputs.

What I want to do is this - set a condition in [`post-if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspost-if) that is evaluated to `true` only if the user-provided flag is set to true.

I tried to write it like this, but it didn't work:

```yaml
post-if: "${{ github.event.inputs.cache }}"
```

I got the following error in CI:

> Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.event.inputs.cache

Is this doable? Or can event inputs simply not be used in `post-if`?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, looks like this is doable.

I just had to delete the braces `{{ }}`:

```yaml
post-if: "github.event.inputs.cache"
```